# R : Parallelising auto.arima()

Tags: r

I am parallelizing the execution of auto.arima() to forecast 500 Route time series, initially I did setting up a parallel token in auto.arima to be TRUE and number of cores to be 10. It did not impact the execution time but just increased the processing calculations to 10 times more, hence taking more time. Then I did something like this:

```
modelsPetrol <- list()

registerDoParallel(cores=28)

start=Sys.time()

foreach(i=1:10, .packages=c("forecast"),.combine=cbind) %dopar% {

  filename <- paste("Model_P",temp[[i]],".rda",sep="") 

   t <- matrix(nrow = 750,ncol=10)

   y <- ts(Train_Petrol[,temp[[i]]], frequency = 6)

   t <- fourier(ts(Train_Petrol[,temp[[i]]], frequency=311.50), K=5)

   modelsPetrol[i] <- auto.arima(y,xreg=cbind(t,holi,wday,schl,weekn),approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE,stepwise=TRUE,lambda = TRUE)

   save(modelsPetrol, file=filename)

    print(modelsPetrol)

   t<-NULL

   y<-NULL
}
```

The code works fine, with less time, but I am struggling to check models, like summary `(modelsPetrol[[1]])` gives an error subscript out of bounds.

Comment: You should have `modelsPetrol[[i]]` instead of `modelsPetrol[i]`.

Comment: Running auto.arima() as multicore processing yields slightly different coef. from the model ran without parallelizing ....which greatly impacts the forecasts.
Can anyone suggest why this is happening.

Comment: Just for clarity, what is "temp" and how was it constructed?

Comment: For correct random generation you need to use doRNG library as doParallel does not handle random seeds.

Answer (score 3):

Finally cracked it...
Sharing with all to have chunk of code that facilitates execution of auto.arima() for 500 Routes using parallel multi core processing:

```
parallel.arima<-function(data) {

library(forecast)

 t <- matrix(nrow = 750,ncol=10)

 y <- ts(data, frequency = 6)

 t <- fourier(ts(data, frequency=311.50), K=5)

 fit <-auto.arima(y,xreg=cbind(t,wday,weekn),approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE,stepwise=TRUE)

 t<-NULL

 y<-NULL

 return(fit)
}

models <-list()

modelsP<-list()

registerDoParallel(cores=20)

start=Sys.time()

models <- foreach(i =1:length(temp)) %dopar% {

 modelsP[[i]] <- parallel.arima(Train_Petrol[,temp[[i]]])

}

end=Sys.time()
```

Works well..!!

Comment: Some advice. Don't use more cores than you have logical cores on your PC. Thus rarely more than 4 or 8 cores.

Comment: Thanks, Yes definitely... running this on 28 core machine...

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405076/looping-and-auto-arima. Please avoid.

Comment: @RachnaDhand could you figure out why auto.arima() doesn't improve automatically?

Comment: @RachnaDhand could you explain what `temp` is here?