# Automated Fourier Term Selection in Batch Forecasting via Foreach

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, parallel-computing

I'm trying to parallelize my batch forecasting via `foreach`, and I'm pretty comfortable doing this via `auto.arima` and `xreg` terms, including Fourier terms that are pre-determined/calculated when the batch forecasting is done sequentially via a regular `for`  or a `foreach() %do%` loop.

However, I was inspired by [this chapter](https://otexts.com/fpp2/weekly.html) in Prof. Hyndman's textbook for automated selection of optimal pair of Fourier terms, but I'm not sure how I would implement this in a parallelized `foreach` loop, as even if it's just one univariate series, output of the `foreach` loop would output to a matrix via one of the options in the `.combine` argument, or just a list without it, and determining the "best K" or fitted model wouldn't be exported outside of the loop, (or at least I think?).

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179144/r-parallelising-auto-arima) focuses on a paralellized with Fourier terms, but they're already determined beforehand.

I haven't tried the `fable` package yet, mainly because I know [parallelization is still slow comparable to sequential](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/issues/169). Also an automated process of determining the optimal K value in `fable` hasn't been implemented, [though has been proposed](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/issues/207).

Here's a sample of how I would do it sequentially:

```
# Sequential version
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

list_of_means <-  c(5189.18109,2241.73218,2947.44890,18.62958,32.49026,19.06078,18.75038,24.59941,25.63607,18.11636)

list_of_stdevs <- c(992.247149,474.268766,610.983238,4.776820,9.558881,4.081409,4.441914,7.110687,6.635868,5.090847)

h <- 52

no_series <- 10

series_length <- (h*3)

maxK <- 25

bestKs <- rep(NA,no_series)

sim_models <- vector("list",length=no_series)

sim_series <- matrix(NA,nrow=series_length,ncol=no_series)

set.seed(12345)
for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    sim_series[,i] <- rnorm(series_length,list_of_means[i],list_of_stdevs[i])
    }

sim_series <- ts(sim_series,frequency=(365.25/7),start=decimal_date(ymd("2016-01-31")))

for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
    for(K in seq(maxK)) {
        fit <- auto.arima(sim_series[,i],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=K),seasonal=FALSE)
        if(fit[["aicc"]] < bestfit[["aicc"]]) {
            bestfit[["aicc"]] <- fit[["aicc"]]
            sim_models[[i]] <- fit
            bestKs[i] <- K
        }
    }
}


sim_forecasts <- vector("list",length=no_series)

for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    sim_forecasts[[i]] <- forecast(sim_models[[i]],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=bestKs[i],h=h),h=h)
    }
```

But this implementation is rather slow.

Here's what I'm doing, without doing an automated process of determining the optimal K value in `foreach`:

```
# Parallelized Version without Fouriers
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
library(doParallel)

list_of_means <-  c(5189.18109,2241.73218,2947.44890,18.62958,32.49026,19.06078,18.75038,24.59941,25.63607,18.11636)

list_of_stdevs <- c(992.247149,474.268766,610.983238,4.776820,9.558881,4.081409,4.441914,7.110687,6.635868,5.090847)

h <- 52

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

no_series <- 10

series_length <- (h*3)

maxK <- 25

bestKs <- rep(NA,no_series)

sim_models <- vector("list",length=no_series)

sim_series <- matrix(NA,nrow=series_length,ncol=no_series)

set.seed(12345)
for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    sim_series[,i] <- rnorm(series_length,list_of_means[i],list_of_stdevs[i])
    }

sim_series <- ts(sim_series,frequency=(365.25/7),start=decimal_date(ymd("2016-01-31")))

cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

registerDoParallel(cl)

sim_models <- foreach(i=seq(no_series),.packages=c("forecast")) %dopar% {
        auto.arima(sim_series[,i],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=maxK),seasonal=FALSE)
        }

sim_forecasts <- foreach(i=seq(no_series),.packages=c("forecast")) %dopar% {
        forecast(sim_models[[i]],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=maxK,h=h),h=h)
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing in terms of the implementation of `foreach` that would help me accomplish this?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You might want to consider shifting this question over to stackoverflow given it is more of a programming question and you might find a more helpful audience over there... In saying that I don't think it is inappropriate here.

Comment: Ahh, I didnt know. Should I delete the question and move it over to SO?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot; I could have just used a nested `foreach` loop via `%:%` to store each pair-wise combination of K-value and each of my series/models in a nested list.

By not using the `.combine` argument, things are left simpler (IMO) to have a nested list where each element of our models can be examined (i.e. checking coefficients, AICc/BIC values).

For those who want to know a solution, albeit a clunky, inelegant one, here's my solution:

```
library(forecast)
library(doParallel)
library(lubridate)

list_of_means <-  c(5189.18109,2241.73218,2947.44890,18.62958,32.49026,19.06078,18.75038,24.59941,25.63607,18.11636)

list_of_stdevs <- c(992.247149,474.268766,610.983238,4.776820,9.558881,4.081409,4.441914,7.110687,6.635868,5.090847)

h <- 52

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

no_series <- 10

series_length <- (h*3)

maxK <- 25

sim_series <- matrix(NA,nrow=series_length,ncol=no_series)

#Reproducible rnorm()
set.seed(12345)
for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    sim_series[,i] <- rnorm(series_length,list_of_means[i],list_of_stdevs[i])
    }

#Converting simulated data to time-series
sim_series <- ts(sim_series,frequency=(365.25/7),start=decimal_date(ymd("2016-01-31")))

#Making clusters and registering our parallel backend
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#Parallelized loop where the outer loop is each of the ARIMA models, each iteration of the inner loop is a K-value within [1,25] pertaining to our ARIMA model
sim_models <- foreach(i=seq(no_series)) %:%
        foreach(K=seq(maxK),.packages=c("forecast")) %dopar% {
            auto.arima(sim_series[,i],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=K),seasonal=FALSE)
            }

#Making a matrix, where the rows are the K-values, the columns are each of our ARIMA models, the elements comprising of the AICc values of each pairwise combination of K and model.
aicc_matrix <-matrix(NA,nrow=maxK,ncol=no_series)
for(col in seq(no_series)) {
        for(row in seq(maxK)) {
            aicc_matrix[row,col] <- sim_models[[col]][[row]][["aicc"]]
            }
        }

#Creating an array to store the K-value which minimizes our AICc value for each of our models.
bestK <- rep(NA,length=no_series)
for(i in seq(no_series)) {
    bestK[i] <- which(aicc_matrix[,i]==min(aicc_matrix[,i]))
    }

#Creating a new list which will consist of only the ARIMA models where the K-value Fourier term has our AICc minimized.
sim_models_best <- vector("list",length=no_series)
for(i in seq(no_series)) {
        sim_models_best[[i]] <- sim_models[[i]][[bestK[i]]]
        }

#Creating forecasts based off the models we just created and their corresponding optimal K-value.
sim_forecasts <- foreach(i=seq(no_series),.packages=c("forecast")) %dopar% {
        forecast(sim_models_best[[i]],xreg=fourier(sim_series[,i],K=bestK[i],h=h),h=h)
        }
```

This is my first post, and I realize now (and based off of Andre B's suggestion) that this should have probably been posted on StackOverflow.

However I do not want to spam this question so I will leave it here (unless advised otherwise), as I believe it can still be relevant here and of some help to people wanting to speed up batch forecasts while not going through tedious testing to find the optimal K-value for pairs of Fourier terms for their weekly-based forecasts.